# Remove duplicates from SQL calculated column

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, calculated-field

First i am sorry if this is a duplicate question but I am not sure how to search on it. This is my issue.

I have a table that is populated from a stored procedure. This sp performs a lot of calculations and then updates the table. The last calculation is a batch qty sum by a length field. I run a cursor (I know bad idea but my boss wants it this way) and with in that cursor I have a second cursor that runs. The outer cursor pulls rows from table-1 (mark#, qty, length) and then the length is compared to the previous pulled length and if they match then the qty's are added up.

While the stored procedure runs and does ALMOST what is supposed to do. The problem is that if the mark numbers are not sequential (example 1, 2, 3) it will place the grand total in all of the rows with the same length.

Here is how the report is currently outputting:

```
Mark#   |Qty |Length  |Batch Qty
---------------------------------
1214-G30|112 |41.4882 |770
---------------------------------
1214-G33|84  |41.4882 |770
---------------------------------
1214-G38|574 |41.4882 |770
---------------------------------
```

What I need it to look like is the following output:

```
Mark#   |Qty |Length  |Batch Qty
---------------------------------
1214-G30|112 |41.4882 | -
---------------------------------
1214-G33|84  |41.4882 | - 
---------------------------------
1214-G38|574 |41.4882 |770
---------------------------------
```

Here is the stored procedure that does all the work:

```
    --Clear CrossBar Report Table
Truncate Table tbl_CrossBarRpt

--Check for open Cursor
If (CURSOR_STATUS('global', 'FACursor'))>=-1
Begin
    If (Select CURSOR_STATUS('global', 'FACursor'))>-1
    Begin
        Close FACursor
    End
    Deallocate FACursor
End


--Dump base data into Cross Bar Report Table
Insert Into tbl_CrossBarRpt(ordernum, materialdesc, marknum)
Select oh.ordernum,gt.material_descFS, od.marknum
From tbl_order_head oh
Join tbl_order_detail od
ON oh.ordernum = od.ordernum
Join tbl_grating_type gt
On oh.gratingnum = gt.grating_type
Where oh.ordernum = @ordernum



--Set variables based on order Number
Declare @bbin as Decimal(18,4); --Bearing Bar Inches
Declare @cbd as Decimal(18,4); --Cross bar Divider
Declare @mtth as Decimal(18,4); --Mount Thickness
Declare @tsp as Decimal(18,4); --Tolerance Support Rod
Declare @tfr as Decimal(18,4); --Tolerance Filling Rod
Declare @totqty as Int; --Total Quantity
Declare @length as Decimal(18,4); --Length
Declare @FA as Decimal(18,4); --Variable FA
Declare @TEM as Decimal(18,4); --Variable TEM
Declare @MEMT as Decimal(18,4); --variable MEMT
--Declare @ReturnValue Decimal(18,4); --Return FA value


--Set Cross Bar Divider
--Exec @cbd = sp_GetCrossbarDivider @ordernum;
Set @cbd = (Select gt.cross_bar_divider
            From tbl_grating_type gt
            Join tbl_order_head oh
            On oh.gratingnum = gt.grating_type
            Where oh.ordernum = @ordernum)

--Set Mounting Thickness
--Exec @mtth = sp_GetMountingThickness @ordernum;
Set @mtth = (Select mt.mnt_thickness
             From tbl_mount mt
             Join tbl_order_head oh
             On oh.banding = mt.mnt_designation
             Where oh.ordernum = @ordernum)

--Set Tolerance Support Rod
--Exec @tsp = sp_GetTolerance @ordernum;
Set @tsp = (Select tl.tol_support_rod
            From tbl_tolerance tl
            Join tbl_order_head oh
            On oh.tolerance = tl.tol_description
            Where oh.ordernum = @ordernum)

--Set Tolerance Filling Rod
Set @tfr = (Select tl.tol_filling_rod
            From tbl_tolerance tl
            Join tbl_order_head oh
            On oh.tolerance = tl.tol_description
            Where oh.ordernum = @ordernum)


--Set Tolerance Support Rod min Mesh
--Exec @MEMT = sp_GetToleranceMesh @ordernum;
Set @MEMT = (Select tl.tol_support_rod_min_mesh
             From tbl_tolerance tl
             Join tbl_order_head oh
             On oh.tolerance = tl.tol_description
             Where oh.ordernum = @ordernum)

--Set up cursor for CrossBar input value
Declare @BearingBar Decimal(18,4);
Declare @CrossBar  Decimal(18,4);
Declare @MarkNum as varchar(25);
Declare @Qty as Int;

Declare FACursor Cursor
For
Select od.bbin, od.cbin, od.marknum, od.qty
From tbl_order_detail od
Where od.ordernum = @ordernum

Open FACursor

Fetch Next From FACursor Into
@BearingBar, @Crossbar, @MarkNum, @Qty

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Begin
    --Calculate FA
    Set @FA = Round((@BearingBar*25.4)/@cbd,0,1)

    Set @TEM = (((@BearingBar * 25.4) - @mtth - @mtth - @tsp) - ((@FA -1) * @cbd))/2

    If (@TEM < @MEMT)
    Begin
        Set @FA = @FA -1
        Set @TEM = (((@BearingBar * 25.4) - @mtth - @mtth - @tsp) - ((@FA -1) * @cbd))/2
        If (@TEM < @MEMT)
        Begin
            Set @FA = @FA -1
            Set @TEM = (((@BearingBar * 25.4) - @mtth - @mtth - @tsp) - ((@FA -1) * @cbd))/2
        End
    End

    If (@TEM < ((@cbd/2) + (@cbd*.05)))
    Begin
        Set @FA = @FA -1
        Set @TEM = (((@BearingBar * 25.4) - @mtth - @mtth - @tsp) - ((@FA -1) * @cbd))/2
    End

    --Calculate Total Qty
    Set @totqty = @Qty * @FA

    --Insert Total Qty value into table Cross Bar Report
    Update tbl_CrossBarRpt Set totqty = @totqty Where marknum = @MarkNum

    --Calculate Length Value
    Set @length = ((@CrossBar *25.4)-@tfr)/25.4

    --Insert Length value into table Cross Bar Report
    Update tbl_CrossBarRpt Set length = @length Where marknum = @MarkNum

    --Get next row of data
    Fetch Next From FACursor Into
    @BearingBar, @Crossbar, @MarkNum, @Qty
End

--Close Cursor
If (CURSOR_STATUS('global', 'FACursor'))>=-1
Begin
    If (Select CURSOR_STATUS('global', 'FACursor'))>-1
    Begin
        Close FACursor
    End
    Deallocate FACursor
End

--Create Temp table for Batch Qty Processing
Select cbr.marknum, cbr.totqty, cbr.length
into #tbl_BQProcess
From tbl_CrossBarRpt cbr
Order By cbr.length Desc, cbr.marknum

--Set up variables for Batch Qty Processing Cursor
Declare @bMarknum as varchar(25);
Declare @bTotQty as int = 0;
Declare @bLeng as decimal(18,4) = 0.0000;
Declare @bLength1 as decimal (18,4) = 0.0000;
Declare @bLength2 as Decimal(18,4) = 0.0000;
Declare @bQty as int = 0;
Declare @bPrevLeng as decimal(18,4) = 0.0000;

Declare BQOutterCursor Cursor
For
Select cr.marknum, cr.totqty, cr.length
From tbl_CrossBarRpt cr
Where cr.ordernum = @ordernum

Open BQOutterCursor

Fetch Next From BQOutterCursor Into
@bMarkNum, @bTotQty, @bLeng

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Begin
    If @bPrevLeng = @bLeng
        Begin
            Goto Cont
        End
    Else
    Begin
        Declare @ibMarknum as varchar(25);
        Declare @ibTotQty as int = 0;
        Declare @ibLeng as decimal(18,4) = 0.0000;
        Declare @ibLength1 as decimal (18,4) = 0.0000;
        Declare @ibLength2 as Decimal(18,4) = 0.0000;
        Declare @ibQty as int = 0;

        Declare BQInnerCursor Cursor
        For
        Select bqp.marknum, bqp.totqty, bqp.length
        From #tbl_BQProcess bqp
        Order by bqp.length Desc, bqp.marknum

        Open BQInnerCursor

            Fetch Next From BQInnerCursor Into
            @ibMarkNum, @ibTotQty, @ibLeng

        While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        Begin
            If @ibLeng = @bLeng
            Begin
                Set @ibQty = @ibQty + @ibTotQty
            End

            Fetch Next From BQInnerCursor Into
            @ibMarkNum, @ibTotQty, @ibLeng
        End
    End

    --Update batch Qty totals
    Update tbl_CrossBarRpt
    Set batchqty = @ibQty
    Where marknum = @bMarknum

    --Close Inner Cursor
    If (CURSOR_STATUS('global', 'BQInnerCursor'))>=-1
    Begin
        If (Select CURSOR_STATUS('global', 'BQInnerCursor'))>-1
        Begin
            Close BQInnerCursor
        End
        Deallocate BQInnerCursor
    End


    Cont:

        --Update Prev Length to current length
        Set @bPrevLeng = @bLeng

        Fetch Next From BQOutterCursor Into
        @bMarkNum, @bTotQty, @bLeng



    End

    --Close Outter Cursor
    If (CURSOR_STATUS('global', 'BQOutterCursor'))>=-1
    Begin
        If (Select CURSOR_STATUS('global', 'BQOutterCursor'))>-1
        Begin
            Close BQOutterCursor
        End
        Deallocate BQOutterCursor
    End

    --Drop temp table
    Drop Table #tbl_BQProcess
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can keep the duplicates out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you consider creating reports with SQL Server Reporting Services, rather than creating reports with stored procs?

Comment: Yes but i am not sure about all the calculations that need to be done.

Comment: I think people who writing such procedures should be fired.

Comment: Hmmm, not following the orders of ones boss ALSO can get you fired. Or did you not see the line above that stated "My BOSS wants it this way"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why the insistence on using cursors, but I think your entire outer and inner cursors could be replaced by this:

```
select cbr.marknum, 
cbr.length,
case when row_number() over(partition by cbr.length order by cbr.length desc, cbr.marknum desc) = 1 
then sum(cbr.totqty) over (partition by cbr.length order by cbr.length, cbr.marknum) else null end batchqty
from tbl_CrossBarRpt cbr
order by length, marknum
```

If you need to actually update `tbl_CrossBarRpt` with the batchqty instead of just selecting the value, you could do that like this:

```
update tbl_CrossBarRpt
set batchqty = x.batchqty
from tbl_CrossBarRpt t
join (select cbr.marknum, 
      case when row_number() over(partition by cbr.length order by cbr.length desc, cbr.marknum desc) = 1 
      then sum(cbr.totqty) over (partition by cbr.length order by cbr.length, cbr.marknum) else null end batchqty
      from tbl_CrossBarRpt cbr) x on x.marknum = t.marknum
```

Comment: It does do all the calcs but at what point wold I do the insert into a table to store them?

Comment: I got this to work for the calculations. Thanks so much!